# What will be the distanceFunction parameter for elki DBSCAN?

Tags: java, image-processing, cluster-analysis, dbscan, elki

```
DBSCAN<NumberVector> dbscan = new DBSCAN<NumberVector>(distanceFunction,0.5,10);
dbscan.run(db);
```

Here what should I put in distanceFunction

Comment: Did you even google for "distance function"?!?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), use

```
EuclideanDistanceFunction.STATIC
```

or

```
new EuclideanDistanceFunction()
```